# Is it possible to generate a variable name in terraform

Tags: terraform

So i want to get the variable in the terraform remote state, however we have a number of different one per environment on the shared route53

So for a given environement, we want to pull the zone id out as such;

zone_id = data.terraform_remote_state.route_53.route53_zone_**${var.environment}**_id

How would I do this please.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is not possible to use arbitrary dynamic strings as variable names.

However, in this particular case the outputs from `terraform_remote_state` are collection values and so you can use the index syntax to access a dynamically-built key from your map value:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.outputs.route53["route53_zone_${var.environment}_id"]
```

---

With that said, if possible I would recommend structuring the output values better so that the Route53 zone ids are given as a map by environment, so that this can be obtained in a more intuitive way.

For example, you could make your `route53` output be a map of objects whose keys are the environment names:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.outputs.route53[var.environment].zone_id
```

```
output "route53" {
  value = tomap({
    production = {
      zone_id = aws_route53_zone.production.id
    }
    staging = {
      zone_id = aws_route53_zone.staging.id
    }
  })
}
```

Or, if you have a variety of different per-environment settings you could structure it as a single output value that is a map of all of those per environment settings keyed by environment name:

```
data.terraform_remote_state.outputs.environments[var.environment].route53_zone_id
```

```
output "environments" {
  value = tomap({
    production = {
      ec2_vpc_id      = aws_vpc.production.id
      route53_zone_id = aws_route53_zone.production.id
    }
    staging = {
      ec2_vpc_id      = aws_vpc.staging.id
      route53_zone_id = aws_route53_zone.staging.id
    }
  })
}
```

This doesn't change anything about the ultimate result, but grouping things by your environment keys in your outputs is likely to make your intent clearer to future maintainers of these configurations.

(You might also consider whether it'd be better to have a separate configuration/state per environment rather than managing them altogether, but that is a big topic in itself.)